# How to check string is laid out in correct format (Python)

Tags: python, string, comparison

I am coding a program which needs to import log files.
The user must input the name of the file in the correct order of 'DD-HH.MM' (day, hour, minute). Is there any way to validate that the users input is in the correct order?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use regular expressions, or try to parse the date with `time.strptime` and see if there are any exceptions. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime

The `strptime` way could be something like this:

```
try:
    time.strptime(input_string, "%d-%H.%M")
except ValueError:
    print("Incorrect date format")
```

Be sure to check the docs and see if the placeholders (`%d`, `%H`, ...) really represent the ranges and formats you want to check

Comment: Ah you beat me to it. Thank you

Comment: Hmmm.... My copy of Python seems to prefer `time.strptime(input_string, "%d-%H.%M")`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GordThompson You're not missing anything. `strptime` is correct, `strftime` does the exact opposite. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this regular expression: `\d\d-\d\d\.\d\d` (I'm not great at writing regular expressions, correct me if I'm wrong). You might also want to check that the date / hour / minute values are valid (i.e. within range).

```
import re
input = '12-12.12'
if re.match('\d\d-\d\d\.\d\d', input):
    print("it matches!")
else:
    print("it doesn't match!")
```

**EDIT:** the answer above is probably better.

**EDIT EDIT:** `[0123]\d-\d\d\.[0-5]\d` would be a slightly better regexp, it validates the month and minute but not the hour.

Comment: Thank you for the help though. It's my computing project so it's really helpful to have both versions because the I can compare and explain why I used that way of doing it :)

Comment: Thanks for elaborating the regexp way! One could also make sure that e.g. day is in the correct range with `[0123]\d` instead of `\d\d`

Comment: @Teyras Thanks for the advice! How would I go about checking the hours ? (i.e. if the first digit is 0 or 1, the second digit can be any; if the first digit is 2, second digit can be 0-3). This is my unfinished regex: `[0123]\d-[012]\d\.[0-5]\d`

Comment: Hours in 24-format could be matched like this `([01]\d|2[0123])`.